# What would be the necessary changes when moving API from test to Prod?

Tags: rest-api, deployment

When moving from testing to Prod we will begin using a Prod API site with a different URL. So some of the components which will need to be updated will include Named Credentials, Apex, and HTTP Callouts in Flows, as well as new API keys.

Is it possible to keep the same Named Credentials which I am currently using in my sandbox and just change the URL & API Keys ? Or do I need to build a whole new Named Credential with the new prod URL & API Keys ? I'm not sure of what is created in the back end when the Named Credential & External Credential are initially created to know if other components would also need to be changed as well.

I think I will need to completely rebuild the HTTP Callouts in the flows with the new URL regardless of whether or not I need to make new Named Credentials or not. I believe the test URL is hard coded into the flow element, and an External Service is created which I believe also has test URL references within it.

The only changes that will be needed to Apex will involve editing the URL endpoints if the Named Credential changes.

Ideally, I would like to make the minimal amount of changes before deployment. But I also don't want to overlook changes that need to be made/created when the component is created.

Any thoughts ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Opinion-based: We have separate Named Creds for PROD and Staging but CMDT that points at which Named Cred to use at runtime; Deploying Named / External Creds is tricky because of secrets.  We use Gearset environment variables to coerce the PROD value of the CMDT referenced Named Cred

Comment: Would I just be better off creating new Named Credential/External Credential of the same name directly in the Prod ? And putting in the new API Keys and Permission Sets. And then just deploying all the types of components I named previously from the sandbox ? Would that actually work ?

Comment: If you do that, then when you create a sandbox, you'll get a Named Cred created pointing at PROD third party systems. We used separate staging/prod named creds and when sandbox was created, we had an apex sandbox postinstall script run that changed the CMDT references to the staging Named Cred so our dev in the sandbox used the staging 3rd party systems. Not bulletproof but avoided manual work

Comment: My future sandboxes would have Named Cred pointing at Prod third systems regardless, won't they ? They're going to get whatever Named Cred are in the Prod and the Named Cred in Prod will have a Prod URL in it.

Comment: if that is what you want, fine. But if the external system is one you update via the callout, you might not want the sandbox to update a PROD external system ...just say'in; YMMV

Comment: Yes - but I didn't say I wanted them to have them. I just said they'd get them from the creation. I don't think there's any way to avoid that when creating new sandboxes, is there ? I would probably go in and manually change these in the sandbox after the creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Opinion-based*

Here's what we do

- Two named credentials per endpoint (as an example, let's assume we callout to Jira)

  - `JIRA` and `JIRA_Staging`
- Custom Metadata that references per callout which Named Credential to use at runtime. For example, a field in a CMDT called `Jira_NamedCredential__c`.  In sandboxes, it has the value `JIRA_Staging` and in Production, a value of `JIRA`

  - All code / automation references the CMDT to locate the Named Credential.  Apex uses a selector layer to access.
  - Side benefit of the CMDT is you can mock the CMDT selector so your  apex unit tests don't rely on any org CMDT metadata (test isolation)
- When a sandbox is created,

  - Both Named Credentials are copied to the Sandbox
  - The CMDT is also copied to the sandbox and it points at the PROD NamedCredential: `JIRA`
  - A sandbox postcopy Apex runs and goes through all the CMDT and replaces the values from `JIRA` to `JIRA_Staging`, `Hubspot` to `Hubspot_Staging`, etc. This only works if you have some sort of naming conventions.
  - Optional, delete the PROD Named Credential from the sandbox

This was an acceptable solution for us that ensured that staging systems only called out to external staging systems and involved the least amount of manual work. It does mean you have to enforce code review discipline to see that all Named Credential identification is done through CMDT.

Comment: thank you very much. That was impressive. I'm going to sound lame in comparison, but after reviewing over the past couple days we're going with the method of simply changing the URL of a newly deployed Named Credentials to fit the final destination's needs, whether it is a new sandbox or Prod). It's not sexy, but in our case after seeing that we can account for all of the other updates we will need which will automatically happen by simply updated the Named Credential URL, it made sense.